# Make single query for news with comment counter

Tags: sql

I have two tables: `news` and `comments`.

I need to write a query for news content and comments count.

I've tried

```
SELECT 
    news.id, news.title, news.date, news.author_name, news.short_content,
    COUNT(com.comment)
FROM 
    php_base.news 
LEFT JOIN 
    php_base.comments AS com ON news.id = com.news_id 
ORDER BY 
    date DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I guess there should be a lot of "AS". Anybody can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.date, n.author_name, n.short_content,
       COUNT(c.comment) as cnt
FROM php_base.news n LEFT JOIN
     php_base.comments c 
     ON n.id = c.news_id
GROUP BY n.id, n.title, n.date, n.author_name, n.short_content,
ORDER BY n.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: one more question, how to use this count, is it comming inside $result array?

Comment: @AndreySmolin . . . Give it an alias (such as `cnt`) and access it like any other column.